# BooleanField not updating: Django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django by building an example app in which students can choose to participate in study sections. The participate action is a BooleanField that I would like the students to be able to check or uncheck and update. It is unchecked by default and I am able to check it and save the form. But when I go to update the form the box is unchecked. How can I set up the form, model, and view so that the participate field can be saved and updated?

models.py

```
class StudentAnswer(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='study_answers')
    study = models.ForeignKey(Study, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='study_participate', null=True)
    participate = models.BooleanField('Participate?', default=False)
```

forms.py

```
class ViewStudyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = StudentAnswer
        fields = ('participate', )
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@student_required
def participate_study(request, pk):
    study = get_object_or_404(Study, pk=pk)
    student = request.user.student

    total_details = study.details.count()
    details = student.get_details(study)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ViewStudyForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                student_answer = form.save(commit=False)
                student_answer.student = student
                student_answer.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Congratulations! You signed up to participate in the study %s!' % (study.name))
                return redirect('students:study_list')
    else:
        form = ViewStudyForm()
    progress=100
    return render(request, 'classroom/students/past_study_form.html', {
        'study': study,
        'details': details,
        'form': form,
        'progress': progress
    })
```

Comment: try smth like this: `...else: participate = StudentAnswer.objects.get(id=pk).values('participate'); form = ViewStudyForm(initial={'participate': participate})`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
....
else:
    participate = StudentAnswer.objects.get(student=student).values('participate')
    form = ViewStudyForm(initial={'participate': participate})
```

This should take boolean `participate` from your StudentAnswer instance and assign it to your form.
More informations is here in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values).

Comment: Hi Chiefir. Thank you for the answer. This almost solved my issue, but initial does not play well with bound forms. My solution based off this was to use `... else: instance = StudentAnswer.objects.filter(student_id=patient.pk, study=study.pk).first(); form = ViewStudyForm(instance=instance)`

Comment: initial filled the `participate` field but left the ForeignKey fields for patient and study blank, so I could not save the form. I was going to bypass this behavior by adding the patient and study fields as hidden, but then I read about `instance` and it seemed like a simpler solution.